# Getting data out of a struct for use in a table view

Tags: swift, macos

I'm unable to get a struct containing vars loaded from JSON into a format suitable for a table view

I've been playing around with this code for a while, done plenty of reading but I'm just plain stuck. I can get data from the server fine and print it to the console. I notice that the data is printed as KEY: "value" rather than "KEY":"value" and that might have something to do with it. Also as the code is right now I can count the number of rows correctly and display the value of FIRST in the table view. What I can't figure out is how to access the other variables for display. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

static var globalPatientInstance: [Patient] = []

var gotJSON: ([Patient], Error?) -> Void = { (patients, error) in
    print("patients from gotJSON: \(patients)")

    globalPatientInstance = patients

    // this returns an error: "Type 'Patient' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"
    /*
     for (key, value) in patients[0] {
     println("\(key) -> \(value)")
     tableArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
     }
     */
    print("patients from gotJSON: \(globalPatientInstance[0])")
}

@IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.delegate = self as NSTableViewDelegate
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    let url = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.25/backend/returnA")
    let returnA = URLRequest(url: url!)

    retrieveJSON(with: returnA, completionHandler: gotJSON)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


func retrieveJSON(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping ([Patient], Error?) -> Void) {

    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {

        // completion handler argument
        (data, response, error) in

        // completion handler
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Did not recieve data")
            completionHandler([], error)
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let patients = try decoder.decode(Array<Patient>.self, from: data)
            // print(Patient)
            completionHandler(patients, error)
        }
        catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
            completionHandler([], error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return ViewController.globalPatientInstance.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    var result: NSTableCellView


    result = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    result.textField?.stringValue = ViewController.globalPatientInstance[row].FIRST

    return result
}
}
```

This code runs fine. The array contains three structs and the value of FIRST is successfully displayed in the table view when the button is pressed.

Comment: I don't see any structs in your code?

Comment: Does `ViewController.globalPatientInstance.count` return more than 1?

Comment: Sorry, I have the struct in another file. It's just a simple collection of vars, all typed as String. I can post some code if needed but there are 70+ vars in there.

Comment: Chris, this returns the correct amount of structs in the array, in this case 3.

Comment: i think you should tableView.reloadData() again inside `var gotJSON:` at last line. because its async call.

Comment: Thanks Mnemonic, doing that gives an error: "Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> (ViewController)' has no member 'tableView'" so I just hooked it up to a button for a manual reload for now. My main focus is getting the data into the table view, thanks!